# What should I do to figure out what has happened to my paper?

Tags: journals

Some months ago I wrote a paper with the help of a professor who sent the paper to a journal as the "corresponding author". I have since cut contact with the professor since he lied repeatedly to me on some unrelated matter. I am afraid that he may have removed the paper from the journal since I can't see its status.

Comment: I guess this is between you and the professor. I do not see what anybody else (including the editor of the journal) could do. In any case, if a paper is being removed, then you would receive a notification of its removal. So, most probably, it is still under review.

Comment: I have sent an email to the journal support in order to learn the status of the paper.I don't trust the professor anymore.

Comment: @PsySp: In many journals, only the corresponding author is notified of changes to the paper's status.  They leave it up to the corresponding author to pass the information along to other authors.  So I would not assume that OP would have been notified by the journal if the paper was withdrawn.

Comment: @NateEldredge You are probably right although, in my experience, the entire set of authors is notified (I really can't remember any time where I had to forward the decisions to my co-authors)

Comment: Perhaps the problem is even more serious if the professor is truly unethical. It would be useful for you to search for his recent publications to see if you were cut out as an author. I hope not, but worth a check. If it turns out that this is the case, you may have the basis for a formal ethical complaint.

Comment: The paper was published a while ago.The professor changed the first author but still is listed as a corresponding author although this is due to the journal defining corresponding authors as those responsible for the submission of the paper than the main contributors of its ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, after a manuscript is submitted to a journal, all the co-authors should receive an email from the editor office or from the editor in charge which will let you know your rights and ways to communicate with the journal. If the under review time is already very long since the paper has been submitted, you can try to reach the journal just by email. But yet for some journals, only the corresponding author can receive the notification, if that is the situation, you have to solve the problem between you and your professor. Alternatively, you can still try to reach the journal for the status of the paper. But eventually, the review comments will be sent to the corresponding author.

Comment: This is contrary to my experience - I've only rarely seen systems that notify *all* the authors. Usually only the corresponding author is included in correspondence. (That's why they're the corresponding author, otherwise the designation is useless...) Perhaps this varies by field?

Comment: @rturnbull I mean the first time when the corresponding author submits the paper, basically most of the journals will send an email, not exactly from the editor office, maybe from the tracking system they use, to all the authors. In this sense, they want to notify all the co-authors that your contribution is now under review.

Comment: Again, that isn't my experience; usually only the corresponding author is included on *any* emails, automated or otherwise. There are exceptions, though. I imagine this is likely field-dependent.

Comment: I received an answer from the journals support team in which they  reported my article review status.I also asked them as to who was put first author in the paper (since it has a field for that in the article submission form) but they ignored that question.